# Categories and instance variables

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am attempting to add a category to `NSMutableArray` to allow me to use it as a 2D array (backed by the 1D array, with a method to convert x & y indexes into a flat index). As I am not allowed to add instance variables to a category, how should I keep track of row and column counts which are required to calculate the index into the array?

Here is the interface:

```
@interface NSMutableArray (TK2DMutableArray)
- (id) initWithColumns:(int) columns rows:(int) rows;
- (id) objectAtColumn:(int) col row:(int) row;
- (void) putObject:(id) object atColumn:(int) x Row:(int) y;
@end
```

And here is the implementation:

```
@implementation TK2DMutableArray

- (id) initWithColumns:(int) x rows:(int) y {
    self = [self initWithCapacity:x * y];

    return self;
}

- (id) objectAtColumn:(int) col row:(int) row {
    return [self objectAtIndex:[self indexAtColumn:col row:row]];
}

- (void) putObject:(id) object atColumn:(int) x row:(int) y {
    [self replaceObjectAtIndex:[self indexAtColumn:x row:y] withObject:object];
}

- (int) indexAtColumn:(int) col row:(int) row {
    return (col + (row * rows));
}

@end
```

I originally coded it up as a subclass of `NSMutableArray`; I now know that was a mistake having read up a little on class clusters. The problem is right there in the last method - what should I do with `rows`? It'd be a regular old ivar if I was subclassing.

I'm fully expecting to be told to create a new class with an `NSMutableArray` as a property, but I wanted to see if there was a way to do it with categories first.

Many thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-C: Instance Variable in Category](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162589/objective-c-instance-variable-in-category)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On 10.6 and later (I'm not sure about iOS), you can use `objc_setAssociatedObject` to associate arbitrary things to an object, see [this Apple doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Articles/ocAssociativeReferences.html). You can use this mechanism to "add" and ivar.

But I think it's better for you to create a new class with an `NSMutableArray` as a property. That way, you can distinguish a 1d array and a 2d array at the level of the types, so that the compiler can warn you. For example, you don't want to accidentally use `objectAtIndex:` on a 2d array, right?

Comment: OK thanks, worth a try. Associations might work but I agree with you: new class it is.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need a class that has the interface of `NSMutableArray` **and** your 2d array operations you probably should subclass `NSMutableArray`. Since this is a class cluster you also must implement the primitive operations of `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray`. These are `count`, `objectAtIndex:`, `insertObject:atIndex:`, `removeObjectAtIndex:`, `addObject:`, `removeLastObject`, and `replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:` as well as any `init`-Methods you require. You then could implement the storage yourself or simply forward them to a `NSMutableArray` instance variable.

But you’re probably better off with a new class for your 2d arrays as Yuji suggested.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply Sven. It's way too much work for such a simple requirement. A new class with the backing array as an ivar will work fine, but it's nice to have the full list here should I need it for something else.